# DataGridView from Binary File

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading data out of a binary file into structs in C#.  What's the best way to populate a DataGridView with these records?  I've only ever used the Binding with actual databases and in fact all the examples I can find cover using flat text files or databases.  Should I not be using the DataGridView at all?  Should I be creating a DataTable and binding it to the DataGridView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are reading the file into an array of structs or a list of structs. Just bind the array or the list to the DataGridView.

Comment: In many cases with .NET, it's best to try it first. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144480/what-is-the-most-under-valued-part-of-net/1144504#1144504.